# Protractor - Error: Failed: WebDriverError

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I have a protractor project that It starts and runs specs as I expect but after almost 2 minutes it starts getting this error on rest of test cases. I don't know why. It had run perfectly one week ago but now I faced  that error and it doesn't give (or I can't see) any detail about error.

> ```
> "Error: Failed: WebDriverError
> at stack (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:2200:17)
> at buildExpectationResult (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:2170:14)
> at Spec.expectationResultFactory (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:777:18)
> at Spec.addExpectationResult (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:450:34)
> at Env.fail (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:1192:25)
> at Function.next.fail (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasmine-core\\lib\\jasmine-core\\jasmine.js:4046:19)
> at Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\jasminewd2\\index.js:64:48
> at ControlFlow.emit (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\events.js:62:21)
> at ControlFlow.shutdown_ (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2565:10)
> at shutdownTask_.MicroTask (Z:\\dev\\lmw\node_modules\\protractor\node_modules\\selenium-webdriver\\lib\\promise.js:2490:53)"
> ```

Information about project: it runs two browser and using chromedriver_2.31.exe.

protractor.conf.js=>

`directConnect: false,
splitTestsBetweenCapabilties: true,
multiCapabilities:[
        {
            shardTestFiles: false,
            maxInstances: 1,
            maxSessions: 1,
            sequential: true,
            parallelCapability: true,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            specs: [
                './tests/login/*.js',
                './tests/header/*.js',
                './tests/my-profile/*.js',
                './tests/nominee/*.js',
                './tests/left-menu/*.js',
                './tests/contact-us/*.js',
                './tests/relations/*.js',
                './tests/coordinator/*.js',
                './tests/sitemap/*.js',
                './tests/landing/*.js',
                './tests/vouchers/*.js',
                './tests/extend/*.js',
                './tests/activity/*.js'
            ]
        },
        {
            shardTestFiles: false,
            maxInstances: 1,
            maxSessions: 1,
            sequential: true,
            parallelCapability: true,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            specs: [
                './tests/enrollment/*.js',
                './tests/claim-/*.js',
                './tests/transfer/*.js',
                './tests/donate/*.js',
                './tests/buy/*.js',
                './tests/calculator/*.js'
            ]
        }
    ]`

package.json =>
`{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-cli": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.2.0",
    "protractor": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.0.0"
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using your office laptop ,can you check whether it has any encryption in the system. Few of these encryptions corrupt the node modules , which results in the failure of the test cases.

This is the only reason I could guess since you ran all your test cases earlier

PS : I faced the same issue

Comment: I solved the the problem today. It is about package.json. I change those lines in my package.json if you interest :) 

   **"grunt-protractor-runner": "5.0.0",**
    **"protractor": "<5.0.0",**

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. This is  a new information for me